# KafkaConnectionError: 111 ECONNREFUSED

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I want to produce and consume kafka topic through a simple python script.
As explained in: https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-apache-kafka-in-python-604b3250aa05 I have created publish_message and connect_kafka_producer using bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'] and produced a simple "Hello message" as below:

```
kafka_producer = connect_kafka_producer()

publish_message(kafka_producer, 'Hello_topic', 'Hello', "Hello")
```

When I try to run this python function, I see below errors:

> DEBUG:kafka.metrics.metrics:Added sensor with name
> node-bootstrap-0.latency
>
> DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0
> host=localhost:9092  [unspecified None]>: creating new
> socket
>
> DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0
> host=localhost:9092  [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>:
> setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
>
> INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0
> host=localhost:9092  [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>:
> connecting to localhost:9092 [('127.0.0.1', 9092) IPv4]
>
> ERROR:kafka.conn:Connect attempt to <BrokerConnection
> node_id=bootstrap-0 host=localhost:9092  [IPv4
> ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]> returned error 111. Disconnecting.
>
> INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0
> host=localhost:9092  [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>: Closing
> connection. KafkaConnectionError: 111 ECONNREFUSED
>
> DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0
> host=localhost:9092  [IPv4 ('127.0.0.1', 9092)]>:
> reconnect backoff 0.04205048432501722 after 1 failures
>
> DEBUG:kafka.client:Give up sending metadata request since no node is
> available

My question is,

1. Is it enough to install kafka-python using "pip install kafka-python" ? or should I need to download zookeeper and kafka seperately ?
2. As mentioned in https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/, I can not see server.properties file to change advertised.listeners to localhost:9092, is this because I have not installed kafka and I am only using "pip install kafka-python" ?

Comment: Did you start the services?

Comment: Do we need to install kafka seperately to start the service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have not installed kafka

Not clear what you're expecting to produce/consume from, then

> should I need to download zookeeper and kafka seperately

Yes. You need to install, configure and start the servers before running clients that connect to these services